# Как сделать overflow: visible для отдельного элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, есть абстрактный контейнер, например, `.container` который имеет свойство `overflow: hidden`, внутри него есть элемент, например, `label`, который в свою очередь имеет абсолютное позиционирование, и мне его нужно вынести за блок, разумеется свойство `overflow: hidden` не дает мне это сделать, как мне решить эту проблему? Может через JS?

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label.error {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="label-control"><br>
            <span class="label-text">Ваше имя</span><br>
          </label><br>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-53"><input name="text-53" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control required error" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" type="text"><label id="text-53-error" class="error" for="text-53">Это поле обязательное.</label></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Только если вынести label из контейнера, или иным образом изменить разметку, что бы не возникло такой ситуации.

Comment: @ДенисЛагуткин в том то и дело, что разметка должна оставаться такой, слышал что посредством js можно реализовать, но не нашел примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только так.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  background: darkblue;
}
.overflowed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overflowed">(Overflowing the wrapper)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я так понимаю, что без явно прописанной высоты никак не добиться?